# C# WPF Window открыть, после закрытия

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть класс производый от Window, который закрывается при помощи метода .Close(). Можно ли открыть это же окно? Или обязательно нужно создавать новое? (просто если второе, то это привносит кучу костылей в мой код)

Comment: Если все данные будут храниться у вас в отдельном от окна классе (смотри MVVM), то никаких проблем с открытием нового окна у вас не будет. А по сути вопроса — что вам мешает попробовать открыть? Ну и вместо Close можете попробовать Hide. Но это приведет только к наращиванию костылей, лучше переписать под MVVM пока не поздно, дальше проблемы только усугубятся

Comment: @АндрейNOP, всё и так написано под mvvm, проблема не в сохранении данных, проблема в том, что я работаю над проектом, который 8 лет писал джун+-, и тут такое количество костылей, что их заделывать другими костылями, собственно проблема в том, что тут каждые 2 минуты обновляються поля, а у меня при вызове Set у проперти, если value нужного типа, создаётся окошко, а это обновление, заного вызывает сет, и я теряю ссылку на старое окно

Comment: @АндрейNOP а при закрытии этого окна, если операция не удалась, нужно combobox вернуть в старое значение. И это всё вместе даёт взрывное, костыльное комбо. Так что пытаюсь пока обойтись малой кровью

Comment: Запрещайте обновлять поле, пока не закончилась предыдущая операция

Comment: @АндрейNOP это пока что самое страшное, из возможных решений :D

Comment: Избавьтесь от побочных эффектов, почему какое-то окошко у вас заново вызывает сеттер этого же свойства? У вас должно получиться в итоге что-то вроде: `set { backingField = _someService.GetActualValue(value); }`